# JavaScript execution flow

Tags: javascript, dom-events

#### Is my assumption right?

Given the following code:

```
function test() {
    for(let i=0 ; i < 100000; i++) {
      // Do a set of costly operations that are NOT ASYNCHRONOUS
    }
}

test();

myScriptElement.onload = test;
```

My assumption is "no", there is no chance for *myscriptElement.onload* to be executed (*test* function) before the first *test* call has terminated
… Since JavaScript has a single "thread" which keep on executing instructions until it reaches some asynchronous code, save current callstack/context/etc, put it into a job queue like area, then execute the next eligible item in that queue or wait for one to come in.

Is that right?

Or, should I make sure the first *test* function call has returned, like with the help of a boolean flag:

```
let terminated = false;
myscriptElement.onload = function specificHandler(e) {
    if (terminated) {
        test();
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(specificHandler.bind(null, e), 1000);
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"Since Javascript has a single "thread" which keep on executing instructions until it reaches some asynchronous code,..."* JavaScript will keep on executing even after it encounters asynchronous code. The asynchronous code executes outside of the JavaScript runtime and the results are held in queue until the JavaScript runtime is ready to consume it.

Comment: not even myScriptElement.onload = test; would be executed before the first test() function finishes

Comment: `Is that right ?` --> Sounds right to me.

Comment: Even if you set the `onload` handler before the `test` call, the `onload` would only trigger after that code is done.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I agree, I wasn't explicit enough. Async stuff is being executed outside the js runtime. Meanwhile the JR keeps on executing , peaking next "saved" state (callstack/context etc. stored in its internal kind of jobs queue) until there is nothing left, then wait for more, and so on ... At least, I guess.